# shell command to perl script with awk, grep

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed

Trying to run below shell command to perl script but getting errors, how to convert this shell command to perl ?

```
grep -i -e 'warn' test.txt | awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -i '^[A-Z0-9]' | sort | uniq | sed 's/ *$//'
```

I have tried grep () function for first part which works but no replacement for awk command found working in perl.

Comment: Do you understand what the various parts of that pipeline are doing? Do you know what the ultimate goal of that line is? That's a poor solution to the problem and is not something you want to port literally to perl as you have much simpler ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %uniq;
open my $IN, '<', 'test.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$IN>) {
    next unless $line =~ /warn/i;

    my $second_column = (split /:/, $line)[1];
    if ($second_column =~ /^[0-9A-Z]/i) {
        $second_column =~ s/ *$//;
        $uniq{$second_column} = 1;
    }
}
print "$_\n" for keys %uniq;
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing how one would potentially convert each section of that shell command to perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %seen;

# grep -i -e 'warn' test.txt
local @ARGV = 'test.txt';

while (<>) {
    next unless /warn/i;

    # awk -F ':' '{print $2}'
    chomp;
    my $second_field = ( split /:/ )[1];

    # grep -i '^[A-Z0-9]'
    next unless $second_field =~ /^[A-Z0-9]/i;

    # sed 's/ *$//'
    $second_field =~ s/ +$//;

    # uniq
    $seen{$second_field}++;
}

# sort
print "$_\n" for sort keys %seen;
```

Or aggregated into a single command using a style similar to the shell:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

local @ARGV = 'test.txt';

print "$_\n" for sort +uniq map {s/ +$//r} grep {/^[A-Z0-9]/i} map { chomp; ( split /:/ )[1] } grep {/warn/i} <>;
```